# MySQL Delete Cascade

Tags: mysql

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm wanting to use the 'Delete Cascade' mySQL functionality so that when a user is deleted from the 'user details' table, it deletes their records from the other tables in my database.

After reading through some posts on Stackoverflow and from research I've carried out on the Internet, I've changed my tables to InnoDB and started to change my existing tables.

I've been able to add the 'Delete Cascade With Foreign Key' to my first table, but when I try to do the same to any other table, I receive the following error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table './db369054642/#sql-30d_bd1a57.frm' (errno: 121)
```

But I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error because the first table that I changed worked without a hitch.

Could someone tell me please, are you only able to link the parent table to one child table?

**Parent Table (User Details)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `userdetails`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userdetails` (
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `forename` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `emailaddress` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `passwordhint` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `subscriptionexpiration` date NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `emailaddress` (`emailaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Child Table (detectors)**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `detectors`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detectors` (
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `detectorid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `detectorname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`detectorid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Delete Cascade SQL Statement**

```
ALTER TABLE detectors
   add CONSTRAINT fk_userdetails
     FOREIGN KEY (userid)
     REFERENCES userdetails(userid)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: The usual suspects such as tablespace full / disk full etc. are ruled out, I suppose?

Comment: Can you post the statement you used to create the foreign key? Maybe it's just, that you already have a foreign key with the same name as you try to create?

Comment: Post your schema and query please

Comment: Google is always a first great resource for error messages. When I plug your error into search I get this forum discussion, amongst several other hits - http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,33999,76181#msg-76181. Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE *tableName*` for both tables you are having trouble with (both the source and target). Also please post the SQL you are trying to use to ALTER the source table.

Comment: Hi, I've added the table structures and SQL statment I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do both your table and the referenced table have **indexes** on the involved columns?

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html:

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. (This is in contrast to some older versions, in which indexes
>   had to be created explicitly or the creation of foreign key
>   constraints would fail.) index_name, if given, is used as described
>   previously.

Try to create the necessary indexes first, or show us the output from the `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName` so we can check if the indexes exist and have no name conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the perror utility (it's included with mysql distibutions). It gives a more detailed explanation for error codes and is run from your command line. The error number in your case is 121, so you'd run this on the command line:

```
perror 121
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/perror.html